# how can i fetch the whole word on the basis of index no of that string in perl

Tags: perl

I have one string of line like

```
comments:[I#1278327] is related to office communicator.i fixed the bug to declare it null at first time.
```

Here I am searching index of `I#`then I want the whole word means `[I#1278327]`. I'm doing it like this:

```
open(READ1,"<letter.txt");
while(<READ1>)
{
 if(index($_,"I#")!=-1)
 {
  $indexof=index($_,"I#");
  print $indexof,"\n";
  $string=substr($_,$indexof);##i m cutting that string first from index of I# to end then...
  $string=substr($string,0,index($string," "));
  $lengthof=length($string);
  print $lengthof,"\n";
  print $string,"\n";
  print $_,"\n";
 }
}
```

Is any API is there in perl to find the word length directly after finding the index of `I#` in that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$indexof=index($_,"I#");
$index2 = index($_,' ',$indexof);
$lengthof = $index2 - $indexof;
```

However, the bigger issue is you are using Perl as if it were BASIC.  A more perlish approach to the task of printing selected lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $read, '<', 'letter.txt'; # safer version of open

LINE:
while (<$read>) {
        print "$1 - $_" if (/(I#.*?) /);
}
```

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\PIYUSH\Desktop>
C:\Documents and Settings\PIYUSH\Desktop>ant -f letter.xml
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\PIYUSH\Desktop\letter.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\PIYUSH\Desktop\letter.xml:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: ERROR:- Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: This is an Ant error and not a Perl error. What Bill Ruppert showed is the correct answer in the **question you asked**. JRE 1.6 no longer has `tools.jar`. Ant will report it, but work anyway. If you have a question about this particular error, you need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex instead, a regex will allow you to match a pattern `("I#")` and also capture other data from the string:

```
$_ =~ m/I#(\d+)/;
```

The line above will match and set `$1` to the number.

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Or: `my $number = /I#(\d+)/;`